# Split list of objects in two separate lists

Tags: c#, list

I have list of object with 4 records. I want to split the first two in one list and the last two records in another list.

The list contains below records:

[image]

I want A and B in one list and C and D in another list

Please suggest how this can be achieved in c#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have done so far. Show some code.

Comment: `var list1 = new List<SomeType> { A, B }; var list2 = new List<SomeType> { C, D };`

Comment: There are many many ways you could do this. What's your final goal?  (This looks like a case of the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: `var a = new[]{l[0],l[1]};
 var b = new[]{l[2],l[3]};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
var l1 = list.Take(2).ToList();
var l2 = list.Skip(2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specifically take those items and put on the new lists, you could do something like this:

```
var firstList = fullList.Where(r => r.BarName == "A" || r.BarName == "B");
var secondList = fullList.Where(r => r.BarName == "C" || r.BarName == "D");
```

If they will be always in the same order as you show, maybe the `fullList.Take` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Take.

```
var ListAB = list.Take(2);
var ListCD = list.Reverse().Take(2);
```

Start with grabbing the first two records. Reverse the list (C & D will now be up front) and get the first two records again.

As juharr mentioned in the comments. Skip(2) can be used as well, in order to achieve your needs.

Don't forget to add a reference at the top of your class file: `using System.Linq;`

[Take MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Skip MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Or `list.Skip(2);` for the second one.